# How to pass parameter from popup to parent window in asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, popup

I want to pass parameter with URL to parent window using java script 
i use following code which is worked

```
  function btnCopyclick() 
   {
       var url = "../Users/Workstation.aspx?patientid=20";
       window.opener.location = url;
       window.self.close(); 
   }
```

but while i pass value of parameter by using asp.net Label control it will not work

```
   function btnCopyclick() 
   {
       var patientid = document.getElementById('<%= lblPatientId.ClientID %>').value;
       var url = "../Users/Workstation.aspx?patientid="+patientid+"";
       window.opener.location = url;
       window.self.close(); 
   }
```

help me to resolve this stuff

Comment: Is this code declared in a separate JavaScript file? If so, you can't use ASP.NET code nuggets (`<%...%>`) in there since `.js` files are not processed by ASP.NET. You should, instead, pass the `parentid` as a parameter to `btnCopyclick`.

Comment: No its in asp.net file only , no separation is there

Comment: Then what is not working exactly? Do you get any JavaScript errors when you click a button (or when the page loads)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url = "../Users/Workstation.aspx?patientid="+patientid;
```

is enough. well see output of alert(url) to check your url.

Rest everything is seems to be fine.